# How to send user a CSV file which is created by bot C# BotFramework SDK3

Tags: botframework

As the title, I want to send user a CSV file which is created by bot C# BotFramework SDK3.. I'm going to use webchat. Let user Download it or Copy the users Desktop. Either way is ok. Is it possble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your CSV file is stored in your project folder, to send a CSV file to the user(s), you can refer to the following sample code.

```
var replymes = context.MakeMessage();
replymes.Text = "Here is a CSV file.";

replymes.Attachments.Add(await GetCSVAttachmentAsync(replymes.ServiceUrl, replymes.Conversation.Id));

await context.PostAsync(replymes);
```

*The implementation of GetCSVAttachmentAsync:*

```
private static async Task<Attachment> GetCSVAttachmentAsync(string serviceUrl, string conversationId)
{
    var filePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\csv_files\userinfo.csv");

    using (var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(serviceUrl)))
    {
        var attachments = new Attachments(connector);
        var response = await attachments.Client.Conversations.UploadAttachmentAsync(
            conversationId,
            new AttachmentData
            {
                Name = "userinfo.csv",
                OriginalBase64 = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath),
                Type = "text/csv"
            });

        var attachmentUri = attachments.GetAttachmentUri(response.Id);

        return new Attachment
        {
            Name = "userinfo.csv",
            ContentType = "text/csv",
            ContentUrl = attachmentUri
        };
    }
}
```

*Test result:*

[image]

***Update:***

Store the CSV file in Azure storage blob, and send it as attachment.

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("{storage_connection_string}");

var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var cloudBlobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();

var cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("userinfo.csv");

cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFile(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\csv_files\userinfo.csv"));

var url = cloudBlockBlob.Uri.ToString();

return new Attachment
{
    Name = "userinfo.csv",
    ContentType = "text/csv",
    ContentUrl = url
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. It works. I think it's not good to save it under project folder. I decide to manage it in blob storage.

Comment: Do you know how could create CSV be created in  blob storage and write it?

Comment: Please refer to my updates, the code of storing the csv in Azure storage blob works for me.

Comment: Sorry for my bad descriptions.  CSV is not is stored in my project folder. If possible, I want to send it to user without create a real CSV file( because, something important information would be saved). But user can download it as a CSV file. If it is impossible, I want to try store to Blob storage directly without creating a real file in local.

Comment: Thank you so much. I found if I set my data here to "OriginalBase64" directly, I don't need to create a real file anymore. Is it a proper way to use it?

Comment: The way you told me is to let user click to download. Do you have any idea to open a file in a new website in WebChat which is created by bot?